# How to inform WordPress plugin users that a plugin has changed name?

Tags: wordpress

From what I can tell, it's impossible to change the name of a plugin once it has been uploaded to the repository. I have a plugin called simple-nav-archives, and I'm expanding it to be able to list archives in places other than the navigation, so obviously, it needs a new name.

However, there are currently thousands of people (if the download count means anything) who use my plugin, and I want them to switch to my new one, but I'm not sure the easiest way to facilitate this transition.

Here is what I'm considering:

**Current Strategy:** Upload the new version of my plugin with the new name to the repository. Then, create a new version of the existing plugin that displays some sort of semi-annoying message on the plugins page informing the user that simple-nav-archives is no longer being supported and there is a new version with a new name by the same developer.

Is this the best option? It seems like there must, or at least should, be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the name, just not the link in the repository I am pretty sure. I could have sworn I changed the name in the past, but I could be wrong, or it might have changed. The link is definitely written in stone.

If it is impossible, best not to change the name if at all possible, you will lose a lot of juice, all your stats, and your users will have to start over with installing it and uninstalling the old version. But if it isn't possible...

I think your plan is best, and you should also be sure to update your text file and be blatant all over that it is unsupported and replaced, so that it shows up in the repository.